# Describe the set of complex numbers such that |z |<$1- Re(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

So given 
|z|< $1-Re(z)$

squaring both sides we get:

$x^2+y^2$< $1-2x+x^2$

$y^2<1-2x$ $\bullet$

Supposing that there exists such a number $\lvert z\rvert$=$1-Rez(z)$, suppose $z=x+yi$ by applying

$\lvert z\rvert$$^2$$=x^2+y^2$

$(1-x)^{2} - y^2=x^2$

$1-2x$=$y^2$

This last equation contradicts the inequality $\bullet$

Is this solution correct, if not can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The contradiction comes from the fact that, in the first part you search for $|z|< 1-Re(z)$  and in the second for $|z|=1-Re(z)$. So, what you really want? An inequality or an equality?

Comment: In the first case the inequality should read $$2x^2+y^2<1-2x$$

Comment: it's a mistake by me I changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shaded region represents the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $|z|<1-Re(z)$. The boundary is a parabola.

[image: region of the complex plane]

Comment: A parabola indeed.  We could have expected it:  The boundary is equidistant from a point and a line, by definition a parabola.

Comment: why is it bounded by -1 on the left?

Comment: Hello, and sorry for my late reply. I have been out of here for a while. The region is not bounded by -1 on the left, it is simply that the plot was made from x=-1 to x=1.5. Actually, it is unbounded to the left.