# Describe the set of all complex numbers $z=x+yi$ such that $|z|<1-x$.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

There's a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674739/describe-the-set-of-complex-numbers-such-that-z-1-rez) but the answer doesn't explain anything at all.

$$z=x+yi$$
$$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1-x$$

Then $1-x$ must be greater than $0$, and we have $1-x>0 \implies x<1$.

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1-x \implies x^2+y^2<1-2x+x^2 \implies x<\frac{1-y^2}{2}$$

$x=\frac{1-y^2}{2}$ is a [parabola](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ff2cm1zzws). My textbook says that it's "intersecting the line $x=1$ at $(1,1), (1,-1)$" which is weird because it doesn't, but whatever.

I see that it might intersect some vertical line in the II and III quadrants, the other answer says that this line is $x=-1$, and the set of all complex numbers $z$ is in the area bounded by the porabola and the vertial line. How do we come up with the vertical line $x=-1$?

Comment: The only mention of $x=-1$ is your own _comment_ to the answer to the older question. It seems like you have misunderstood a visual artifact of the _plotting software_ as if it was part of the answer -- but it wasn't. Rather $x=-1$ is simply the left end of the range of $x$ values that the answerer chose to plot, because there wasn't room in the post to show the entire infinite complex plane.

Comment: then this region is not bounded and the set is described by the parabola only?

Comment: I was also confused by my textbook's weird answer

Comment: Correct, everything to the left of the parabola satisfies the inequality. If you want commentary on your textbook's weird answer, you'll probably need to supply an extended verbatim quote or scan from it -- as currently written in the question it's anyone's guess what it's on about.

Comment: It says: "For $z=x+iy$, we clearly need $1-x=1-$real part of $z\geq0$, or $x\leq1$. For such $x$, our condition $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1-x$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2<(1-x)^2$, or $x<\frac{(1-y^2)}2$. The ser of points with $x=\frac{(1-y^2)}2$ is the porabola pointing along the second axis, with the point $(0, 1/2)$ closest to the origin, and intersecting the line $x=1$ at $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. The area bounded by this parabola and the line $x=1$ is the desired set of points."

Comment: Yeah, that is just horribly confused. It looks like the textbook author somehow mistook the correct $\frac{1-y^2}2$ for $\frac{1+y^2}2$ when he sketched the parabola, and then didn't think to verify that the solution he got made sense. Be on the guard for other such mistakes in that book!

Comment: (It's _true_ that all solutions have $x\le 1$, of course -- that just doesn't tell us anything that $x\le \frac{1-y^2}2$ doesn't already tell us).